# Como ver si un puerto esta en uso en Inno Setup?

Tags: pascal, puertos

En mi instalador creado con [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) fue necesario comprobar la disponibilidad de un puerto para instalar y montar un servicio MySQL, ya que si el puerto esta en uso es necesario cambiarlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

despues de intentar muchos metodos para realizarlos encontre una manera de hacerlo:

```
[CODE]

function CheckPortOccupied(Port:String):Boolean;
var
  ResultCode: Boolean;
begin
  Exec(ExpandConstant('{cmd}'), '/C netstat -na | findstr'+' /C:":'+Port+' "', '', 0,
       ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
  if ResultCode <> 1 then 
  begin
   // Log('this port('+Port+') is occupied');
    Result := True; 
  end
    else
  begin
    Result := False;
  end;
end;
```

la manera de implementarlo:

```
function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
var
ocupado : Boolean;

begin
Result := True;
  if (CurPageID = Pagina.ID) then
    begin
      ocupado := CheckPortOccupied('80');
        if (ocupado = True)then
          begin
          Result := False;
          MsgBox('El Puerto '+fieldPuertoServerPage.text+' esta ocupado',mbError,MB_OK)
          end;
    end;
end;
```

Espero que les sea de ayuda.